# pause rich text box and then resume again

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

**What I am doing:**

I am receiving a string of data every second constantly from a serial port. I am processing it and also displaying this string on the rich text box.

**Problem:**

I want the user to go through the old strings and copy any, but user can't do it because data is coming every second and auto-scrolling occurs.

**My desired solution:**

I am thinking to have a check-box 'pause'. when user checks it updating of rich text box stops. and user can go in history and copy a string. but in the mean while I don't want to stop the incoming strings from the serial port as I am doing other things as well with the incoming strings.

So when user uncheck 'pause' checkbox, all the strings which had arrived earlier while user had checked' pause' checkbox also appear on rich text box along with new ones.

is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Basically write the incoming data from the serial port in another buffer when the checkbox is checked and *don't* write it in the RTFBox, as soon as the value of the checkbox changes to `true` again, write all the saved strings from the back buffer into the rtfbox and continue to write into the main buffer / the RTFBox. That would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that when you check the Pause button then every incoming text is appended to a StringBuilder instead of the RichTextBox. When the user uncheck the Pause button you copy everything from the StringBuilder to the RichTextBox

```
// Assume that these are somewhere globals of your forms
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
CheckBox chkPause = new CheckBox();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

protected void chkPause_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!chkPause.Checked)
    {
        rtb.AppendText = sb.ToString();
        // Do not forget to clear the buffer to avoid errors 
        // if the user repeats the stop/go cycle.
        sb.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        // Start a timer to resume normal flow after a timer elapses.
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        t.Interval = GetSuspensionMilliseconds();
        t.Tick += onTick;
        t.Start();
    }
}

protected void onTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkPause.Checked)
    {
        // Set to false when the timing elapses thus triggering the CheckedChanged event 
        chkPause.Checked = false;
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = sender as System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
        t.Stop();
    }
}
```

now in the point where the incoming data is passed to the RichTextBox you could add

```
....
string incomingData = ReceiveDataFromSerialPort();
if(chkPause.Checked)
   sb.AppendLine(incomingData);
else
   rtb.AppendText = incomingData;
```

Comment: thankyou for the reply. also is this a god idea to have a time out that user can pause update to rich text box for few seconds or something? what can be the upper bound in time this case

Comment: I can't say. This should be a configurable option for your users. Sometime 30 seconds till a maximum of 2 minutes. It should not be a memory problem unless you receive a lot of data every second. A timeout is a good idea and esily implementable using a timer that starts when you get the check true and automatically uncheck after a given time

Comment: Added a Timer example to resume normal inflow of data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your eloborate answer. One final thing. Strings that i am storing in string builder are of different colours. How can i make sure that when i do 'rtb.AppendText = sb.ToString();' rich text box also shows the original colours od each string

Comment: Uhm, StringBuilder has no provision to store colors. However, if these colors are the result of some kind of elaboration on the incoming data then you need to apply this elaboation also to the strings stored in the StringBuilder. You could get back the StringBuilder content, split it in many lines and then process each line adding the color required.

Comment: aha good idea. i m now storing the representative colour of each string as well when i do ´sb.AppendLine(text+colour)´. How can i transverse a string builder line wise till the end is reached ? I mean how should i access/read the content of sb so that i can do parsing on each line to get colour and set corresponding rtb.ForeColour for each line of sb.

Comment: AppendLine adds a newline at the end of the string stored in the stringbuilder. You get back the StringBuilder content (ToString()) and split it at the newline (string.Split(newline constant)) obtaining an array of strings, then foreach and split again the data part of the line from the color of the same line